# Query for intersection of dispositions; Protege

Tags: owl, ontology, protege, owl-api, manchester-syntax

I want to identify when an object contains the intersection of two properties, as opposed to either property.

**Example:**

```
object: 
    A (has_disposition some disposition_A; has_disposition some disposition_B)
    B (has_disposition some disposition_B; disjoint with A)

disposition:
    disposition_A
    disposition_B
    disposition_AB (EquivalentTo: disposition and ((disposition_A) and (disposition_B))
```

The object property `has_disposition` takes `object` as its domain and `disposition` as its range.

The following DL Query in Protege using HermiT produces nothing:

```
has_disposition some disposition_AB
```

The following queries give the correct answer:

```
has_disposition some disposition_A (gives A)
has_disposition some disposition_B (gives A, B)
```

The following actions did not help:

- Changing parentheses in the `EquivalentTo` expression.
- Declaring nothing disjoint.
- Declaring each part of the `EquivalentTo` expression separately.

I was unable to find examples of a disposition being defined as the intersection of other dispositions in OGMS, the Infectious Disease Ontology, or the Cardiovascular Disease Ontology.

Answer (score 0):

No results for `disposition_AB` means the equivalent axiom cannot be matched against the individuals you have.

I'm not clear on where the `disposition` type would come from for A and B - I suspect that's not being inferred as you expect.